# Neo4j - Prepare CSV data

Tags: database, neo4j

I will create soon a graph database with Neo4j. My input data will be several CSV files.

I'm reading the documentation, I find some information on how to load the data, how to create the graph and other things. But I don't information on how prepare the data..

How I must structure my différents files ?

I'm looking specificaly a tutorial on how prepare data ? If you have it it will be nice.

Thanks for your help, Regards

Comment: are you planning on using LOAD CSV clause or admin import?

Comment: No, my problem is to learn how order the differents columns in my CSV files.

Comment: Order of columns is not important in your csv file(s). When you load your csv file, you assign row.columnName to node:Name even if columnName is at the rightmost column of your csv.